# Advance approval according to § 81a AufenthG for work permit in Germany, is it the right one?

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card

According to the new [Skilled Immigration Act](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa/skilled-immigration-act/), an employer would receive an Advance Approval document from the foreigners registration office in Germany and would pass it on the qualified professional.

The qualified professional would receive the document before they make an appointment to the relevant embassy/consulate.

Attached below is a document that one got from their employer, but how to verify that it's the Advance Approval document according to § 81a AufenthG?

[image]

What has been done so far:

1. Translated the whole document in English, but that doesn't verify it.
2. No reference to *§ 81a AufenthG* could be found in the document, and that's the reason I'm posting it here.
3. Asked the employer regarding it, and seems like they aren't sure about it either.

Comment: On the face of it, it sounds like the approval from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit* mentioned in § 81a Absatz 3 Satz 4. It's just one element the *Ausländerbehörde* must secure as part of the fast-track procedure. In particular, the document states that this approval is conditional on a finding of equivalence for your degrees and the *Ausländerbehörde* before approving your application. Are you positive your employer did apply for the fast-track procedure?

Comment: This document states that approval cannot be given since the position qualifies for a § 18b (2) AufthG (Blue Card) for which **no permission is needed**. You (or your future employer) must start the visa process to recieve a Blue Card.

Comment: The second sentence from @Relaxed is correct.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The problem with starting the visa process is: if it's not for fast-track procedure, we might have to wait for a year till the embassy in my country issues an appointment.

Fast-track procedure will make sure that one gets an appointment within 3 weeks of asking, no matter what.

Comment: @Relaxed I will confirm with the employer again.

Comment: Your employer should send the letter to the foreigners registration office so that they know that no approval from the Bundesagentur für Arbeit is needed.

Comment: Did you get any answer to your question? I am in the same jam as you here. Not sure if this is the pre approval

Comment: @Taiyiba Sorry I saw your comment now. I'm already in Germany now. The document in the question is surely not the 81a document. I'd answer my own question, and I'd attach a correct 81a document with it that I got from my employer.

Comment: @Arslan Hi Arslan I am facing the same issue, I have this document as well, does this confirm that all the previous steps were approved. Thank you !

Comment: Hi Arslan Ali, can you post that answer you mentioned?  As you see, we've had a second inquiry from someone in a similar situation, so it will surely be helpful to others if you can do that.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the correct document, please?

Comment: I will post the screenshot of the correct document soon, in form of an answer. I have been away, so apologies for that. @phoog